# Angular-Cli: New Project Won't Load

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I get the following message:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
```

Does anybody know why this might be occurring?